# Get the correct format of response data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

I have a yaml file of this format from which i want to extract data:

```
Layouts:
        -
          Name: Default Layout
          LayoutIndex : 1
          LayoutType : Control Room
          ConfiguredSegments:
            LiveA :
                Height : 100
                Id : LiveA
                Left : 0
                Options :
                SerializationId : 
                Top : 0
                Width : 50
                ZIndex : 0
                Color : FF4EB7F2
            Ref1A :
                Height : 100
                Id : Ref1A
                Left : 50
                Options :
                SerializationId : 
                Top : 0
                Width : 50
                ZIndex : 0
                Color : FF3D91BF
```

I have a controller which fetches the layouts based on layout index:

```
export const getSegments = (req,res)=>{
    const { id } = req.params;
    let segmentList =[];
    const getLayout = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(layoutData)); 

    const foundLayout = getLayout.Layouts.find((layout) => layout.LayoutIndex == id);
    segmentList = foundLayout.ConfiguredSegments;
    const segments = JSON.stringify(segmentList, null, 4);
    res.send(segmentList);
}
```

When the above controller code is executed, i am getting the below result:

```
{
        "LiveA": {
            "Height": 100,
            "Id": "LiveA",
            "Left": 0,
            "Options": null,
            "SerializationId": null,
            "Top": 0,
            "Width": 50,
            "ZIndex": 0,
            "Color": "FF4EB7F2"
        },
        "Ref1A": {
            "Height": 100,
            "Id": "Ref1A",
            "Left": 50,
            "Options": null,
            "SerializationId": null,
            "Top": 0,
            "Width": 50,
            "ZIndex": 0,
            "Color": "FF3D91BF"
        }
    }
```

But the actual output i want is of this format:

```
{
"ConfiguredSegments": [
{
"LiveA": {
"Height": 100,
"Id": "LiveA",
"Left": 0,
"Options": null,
"SerializationId": null,
"Top": 0,
"Width": 50,
"ZIndex": 0,
"Color": "FF4EB7F2"
}
},
{
"Ref1A": {
"Height": 100,
"Id": "Ref1A",
"Left": 50,
"Options": null,
"SerializationId": null,
"Top": 0,
"Width": 50,
"ZIndex": 0,
"Color": "FF3D91BF"
}
}
]
}
```

How will i be able to achieve this? I have tried making changes in Yaml file by adding "-" in front of LiveA and Ref1A .
But does not seem to work.

Comment: Try this `res.json({ ConfiguredSegments: foundLayout.ConfiguredSegments});`

Comment: Thanks.This is working but it should be res.json({ ConfiguredSegments: [segmentList] });